# jquery-file-upload progressbar moving backward

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I have a popup modal. I need each time popup opens it will allow only 1 successful file upload. That mean if again popup opens (without refreshing the page) it will allow again a single file upload.
Now this is my code-

```
if(typeof fileuploadobj != 'undefined') {
        jQuery('#fileupload table tbody tr.template-download').remove();
        jQuery('#fileupload table tbody tr.template-upload').remove();
        //fileuploadobj.destroy;
//            jQuery("#fileupload").fileupload('destroy');
    }

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    fileuploadobj = jQuery('#fileupload').fileupload({
        acceptFileTypes:  /(.+wav)/i,
        dropZone: jQuery('.upload_dropzone'),
        autoUpload: true,
        maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
        formData: {some_id: 999}
    });
```

now for each even upload (2nd, 4th etc) progress bar moving right to left.
How to solve this.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the reason of this issue.
Basically all my files were very small (few 100 kbs).
First upload shows the progress bar correctly and progressbar reached to 100%.
When I start second upload progress bar gently comes back to 0% and in this mean time upload is being completed (small size). So progress bar looks like its running backward. I tested using some big files and found it comes back to 0 and then shows original progress.